# how can I migrate reactnavigation navigate function?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Under v4 of react native navigation this code was working

```
export default class ExtScreen extends React.Component {
 getDetail = data => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailView', {data});
 }
}
```

what should i do for v5?

Comment: [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/enjzz8/react_navigation_version_4_and_5_comparison/)
There is some code in video I think perhaps could help you.

Comment: The code is same for navigation between screens in V5 with props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TouchableOpacity
                  key={data.id}
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("ExamConfirm", {
                      examid: data.id,
                      examname: data.exam_name,
                      duration: data.exam_duration,
                      desc: data.instruction
                    });
                  }}
                >
</TouchableOpacity>
```

### Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.1.1",
}
```